# LINQ to SQL sets date but not time...sometimes

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, datetime

wierd problem. I have 3 places/columns where i do this...

```
var o = db.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderID == orderID).First();
o.dateOne = DateTime.Now;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

At this place all is good... value in DB is say 2011-04-01 **12:12:33**

At two other places I do the same for...

```
o.dateTwo = DateTime.Now;
o.dateThree = DateTime.Now;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

These two objects get the correct date, but in the DB it says 2011-04-01 **00:00:00**

I have tried displaying the value of the object just before SubmitChanges. At this point the value is WITH time, e.g 2011-04-01 **12:12:33**

Other info: DB is MS sql, all columns are date/time, .NET 3.5...

Anyone who has experienced the same behaviour??

Comment: What about the SQL-DataType of the columns (dateTwo, dateThree ) are they smalldatetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you capture the SQL statement being sent to SQL Server using SQL Profiler? You'll then be able to tell where the truncation has happened.

```
exec sp_executesql'
UPDATE [MyTable]  SET [dateTwo] = @p0
WHERE ...',
...--and then defining the value of your datetime
@p0 = '2011-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: yes - issuing an sql command is probably also more efficient in my case. Just wondered if there were known issus with this, or an easy fix. Thanks

Comment: @Steen: what I mean is: try to capture what EXACTLY is being sent to SQL Server by LINQ To SQL. This will help determine where the problem lies. If the time precision IS being sent, then it's a SQL Server problem. If not, then it's a C#/LINQ To SQL problem.